# Check for duplicate entry in laravel register form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing a register form in laravel and when the user inserts his identification number which is unique. It returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '49573986Q' for key 'users_nif_unique'
```

```
I have this on the validator form:

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email:rfc,dns','string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'nif' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'regex:/^[0-9]+$/',  'max:8', 'unique:users,nif'],
            'date_of_birth' =>['required', 'date'],
            'first_name' =>['nullable',  'string', 'min:2'],
            'last_name' =>['nullable',  'string', 'min:2'],
            'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);
    }
```

How can I check if the nif is unique before I get that error?

Comment: Is the validator really used correctly? It seems like it should throw an error because `49573986Q` doesn't match your regex rule: `/^[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Can you post how `validator()` is being used?

Comment: It returns an error because that entry it's already on the database

Comment: Yes, because was inserted without actually being validated.

Comment: The letter is added before I insert to the database

Comment: Actually, it is a lot more performant to use the unique constraint and its error message to prevent a duplicate record from being inserted, than trying to use a select to find out if a record is a duplicate. Handle the error in your code properly.

Comment: Yes, more performant but less user friendly and requires a lot more code to handle and display properly for the user to understand. Since Laravel already provides a rule to check for the uniqueness of a value in a table and it's the way it handles validation I suggest keeping the additional query and live with it for the sake of sanity.

Comment: @Paco Pinazo Guna Have you solved your problem? Otherwise we need to see the code producing the error (like your controller method).

Comment: @Dan the user friendliness depends on how you handle the error and what you display back to the user, not on the method that prevents duplicate records from being inserted. Also, the most comfortable way is not alwas the best way to accomplish something. Just because you need to write slightly less lines of code, you should not settle for a less performant and potentially less secure method.

Comment: @Shadow: Honestly, I don't really care about the performance in this scenario and that is really not the problem here. I have never seen anyone in the Laravel community handle this different to what OP does and not a single article, blog post or book regarding this specific way to increase performance in CD operations. And ultimately it's up to the development team how to handle those situations. If my request takes 3 ms longer for a validation which takes place only every so often, I'm fine with that as long as there's no overhead on the code I or my team have to test and maintain.

Comment: @Dan not really sure how error handling, which you would have to do anyway, adds such an overhead to any developer team on code maintenance that you would go for a less performant solution.